# Event-based rather than flow-based systems?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is a very vague question, so I don't know if people will understand it (I'm not even sure I understand the question myself), but here goes. Also, I'm not sure if this is really the right forum to ask, but I thought that it relates to computer science because of the connection to **function calls** (see comment at bottom).

Dynamical systems are formulated (in continuous time) as
$$\begin {align}
&\dot x_1=f_1(x_1,...,x_n)\\
&...\\
&\dot x_n=f_n(x_1,...,x_n)
\end {align}$$

These are **flows over time**. In other words, we have a **stock** for each variable, and a specified **flow** at each point in time, from which we will deduce the stock over time.

Situations in applied science that are captured well by this system are for example:

1. There is an amount of water $x$ in a cup, and we know that every second, an amount $a$ drips through a hole, so that $\dot x=a$.
2. an object is moving with $x$ meters/s towards the earth, and we know that every second, $x$ increases by $9.8m$.

We can of course do this in **discrete time** as well, which **doesn't fundamentally change the idea**:
$$\begin {align}
&\Delta x_1=f_1(x_1,...,x_n)\\
&...\\
&\Delta x_n=f_n(x_1,...,x_n)
\end {align}$$

---

However, **sometimes our logical analysis in an applied setting** doesn't **start** with knowledge of a flow per unit time, but **with knowledge of events**. For example, we might know that in biology, an event called "birth" can occur, which would cause various things to happen (among other things, an increase in the population with unit $1$).

We generally model births in population science (as we do in most of science) also as a flow. Instead of starting with a formal definition of a birth as an event, we simply state that in a given time interval, the population increases. In other words, the analysis starts with the variable population, and with a formula denoting its change over time. In fact the whole concept of a "birth", being an event, never enters the mathematical model, and is only a kind of informal interpretation that we stick to the model.

**I am wondering whether this "informal" leap from the "event" of a birth to a change-over-time, can somehow be formalized.**

**So my question is:**

1. **Is there a (sub-)branch of mathematics that starts its analysis with a formalization of an "event", rather than of a flow?**
2. **Is there any mathematical analysis of "events" at all?**
   I tend to think of events as "function calls" in the programming
   sense. i.e. when a birth occurs, a "birth" function is called and
   this causes various variable changes, and possibly other events.

Comment: As you say, this doesn't have much to do with CS as written. The topic you seem interested in is continuum approximations. There is certainly theory on constructing continuum approximations from discrete models, but, like any exercise in approximation, there's a large amount of art to it in the choice of assumptions and knowing in what regimes the approximations are valid or at least valid for a purpose.

Comment: @DerekElkins, Thank you. Yes I'm not sure if it has anything to do with CS indeed. But my question is really not about continuum approximations at all. It seems my question is rather vaguely formulated as I feared. But I am really interested into thinking about events as analogous to function calls (which is why I asked it in computer science). My question is not at all about discrete dynamical systems, or discrete approximations to continuous time dynamical systems.

Comment: You could consider various forms of state machines, but those *are* discrete dynamical systems. There's also various mathematical approaches to concurrency that focus on "events" either in the space-time sense as in causal structures, or as a form of communication between concurrent processes. (Also, continuum approximations are continuous approximations to discrete systems not the other way around, e.g. fluid dynamics is about molecules but the Navier-Stokes equation is a continuum approximation to that discrete reality.)

Comment: Derek Elkins: there is an answer in this. Discrete event systems have a lot of theory that is firmly within theoretical computer science. Often, events and messages are treated identically in such theory.